# How to create copy of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

I need save this array to another variable

```
var save = array;
```

Now I need splice from `save` first index but when I try it, the index is removed from both arrays.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var save = array;

save.splice(0, 1);
console.log(array);
console.log(save);
```

Comment: Try `array.slice()`.

Comment: Read up on value type vs reference type for the reason why this happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy the array using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) otherwise `save` holds the reference to the original array(Both variables are pointing to the same array).

```
var save = array.slice();
```

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var save = array.slice();

save.splice(0, 1);
console.log(array);
console.log(save);
```

Comment: @Dave : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If it's a flat array with no circular references, you can use

```
var copied_array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original_array));
```

This works for flat objects as well.